# i´m trying to compile a pdf in mardown, but generate the next error

Tags: latex

i´m working on rmardown, i´m trying to compile in pdf, but the console show me an error.

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ^^S (U+0013)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

Try other LaTeX engines instead (e.g., xelatex) if you are using pdflatex. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-unicode.html
Error: LaTeX failed to compile Modelos-de-volatilidad.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Modelos-de-volatilidad.log for more info.
Ejecución interrumpida
```

i have install MIKTEX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the error in the line where it is happening.  There's surely one character that LaTeX is not processing.  Comment or cut the line and run again.  I have had a similar issue when copy pasting from a pdf into LaTeX.